# Handling search button using iPhone browser?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, html, mobile

I'm developing a web application in asp(mobile).

When using the iPhone browser for entering some search text in the search text box **(`<mobile:TextBox ID="txtSearchData" Runat="server" BreakAfter=False></mobile:TextBox>`) ,** the iPhone launches the search keypad and when I click the search button using the iPhone keypad it refreshes the full page, but clicking the search button below the textbox it is working fine.

### Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**Here's my code so far:**

```
<body>
  <mobile:Form ID="frmSearch" Runat="server" Font-Name="NotSet" Font-Size="Small">
    <mobile:DeviceSpecific ID="dsSearch" Runat="server">
      <Choice Filter="isHTML32">
        <ScriptTemplate>
          <link href="StyleSheets/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <meta id="Meta1" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
        </ScriptTemplate>
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <table cellspacing="2" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%">
                <uc1:Header ID="ucHeader" runat="server" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                Find :
              </td>
              <td>
                <mobile:DeviceSpecific>
                  <Choice="isHTML32">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="lstGroups" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="LstGroups_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                  </Choice>
                </mobile:DeviceSpecific>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right"> Search by:</td>
              <td>
                <mobile:SelectionList ID="lstSearchPreferences" Runat="server" BreakAfter=False>
                  <Item Selected=True Text="select" />
                </mobile:SelectionList>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <mobile:SelectionList ID="lstSearchOptions" Runat="server" BreakAfter=False>
                </mobile:SelectionList> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <mobile:TextBox ID="txtSearchData" Runat="server" BreakAfter=False>
                </mobile:TextBox>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trContractorFilter" runat="server" visible="False">
              <td align="right"> 
                <mobile:Label id="lblContractorFilter" BreakAfter=False Runat="server" Visible="True" >
                  Results:
                </mobile:Label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mobile:SelectionList ID="lstContractorFilter" Runat="server" BreakAfter="True" Visible ="True" >
                  <Item Selected="True" Text="Active Permits" />
                  <Item Text="All Permits" />
                </mobile:SelectionList>
                (your permits only)
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <mobile:DeviceSpecific>
                  <Choice="isHTML32">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior=true OnClick="BtnSearch_Click"/>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                  </Choice>
                </mobile:DeviceSpecific>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <mobile:Label ID="lblError" Runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor=Red Visible="false" BreakAfter=False></mobile:Label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
      </Choice>
    </mobile:DeviceSpecific>
  </mobile:Form>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with ASP, it might help if we can look at the actual HTML that gets generated.

Comment: That sounds like a really serious bugg in the framework. What is the generated javascript form event handler?

Comment: You can try the **defaultbutton** property: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP either, but why not just use the HTML5 input type="search" input instead of a button you need to click? 
Also, some of your tags are in uppercase

Comment: The tags are uppercase because they are ASP specific tags for ease of separation (but html is insensitive to it anyways). Are you handling the search feature using "BtnSearch_Click" in CodeBehind? if so you may have to handle the event of "Enter" as well as it seems the "Search" button on the Keypad is just a fancy "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript) and its answer using jQuery, you can write this same code in your page and do the client processing before firing the submit.

Additionally, you can use `$.ajax()` library functions to submit the form asynchronously(within the above discussed code block and not firing the `form.submit()` at all), which will eliminate any page refresh (no matter from where the form submit event is fired.)

```
<form id="hello-world" action="sayhello">
<input type="submit" value="Hello!">
</form>
```

You can attach an event handler like this:

```
$('#hello-world').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    /* Validations go here */
    //this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
    $.ajax({
         url:'your_form_target',
         data:formData,
         success:function(data,textStatus, jqXHR){

         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Action` attribute of `mobile:Form` to `#`.
That should cancel the default postback action of the form, which is executed when the Search button on the keyboard is hit.

[Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/dotnetmobile/control_form.asp)

Answer (score 0):

By default ASP.NET controls make full page postback, to send page data to the server.

For handling AJAX request on asp.net you should use an ScriptManager and UpdatePanel controls or using a client side mechanism like jQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your search BUTTON isn't actually firing the form submission, it's firing a JS function: `onClick="BtnSearch_Click"`

BtnSearch_Click is probably preventing the default action (Submitting the form and reloading the page) from occurring which is what you need to do to your form's default submit action.

I'm not familiar with ASP, so i'm probably way off the mark but you should be able to put a

```
onSubmit="Btn_Click"
```

on the form, which the "search" button on iOS will trigger.