# How to prevent default on form submit?

Tags: javascript

If I do this I can prevent default on form submit just fine:

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // do something
});
```

But since I am organizing my code in a modular way I am handling events like this:

```
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('onsubmit', my_func);

var my_func = function() {
   // HOW DO I PREVENT DEFAULT HERE???
   // do something
}
```

How can I prevent default now?

Comment: The same way. The browser (well, decent ones) pass the event object as a parameter.

Comment: LOL if you want to be bad you could always put `<form onsubmit="return false;">`

Comment: Note: When using the [`onclick` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick), just set it: `elem.onclick = function () { ... };`. Otherwise, you're trying to call a previous handler with the new one as an argument.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Haha hopefully that was a typo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The same way, actually!

```js
// your function
var my_func = function(event) {
    alert("me and all my relatives are owned by China");
    event.preventDefault();
};

// your form
var form = document.getElementById("panda");

// attach event listener
form.addEventListener("submit", my_func, true);
```

```html
<form id="panda" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="The Panda says..."/>
</form>
```

Note: when using `.addEventListener` you should use `submit` not `onsubmit`.

Note 2: Because of the way you're defining `my_func`, it's important that you call `addEventListener` **after** you define the function. JavaScript uses [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) so you need to be careful of order of things when using `var` to define functions.

Read more about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and the [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) interface.

Comment: No, the `return false` doesn't work like you think. Maybe in jQuery, but definitely not with `addEventListener`

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add a parameter to your function and use it inside.

```
var my_func = function(event) {
   
   event.preventDefault();
   
}
```

The parameter inside now represents the parameter from the addEventListener.

Answer (score -1):

i known this is old, but just for the sake of it. 
try

```
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('onsubmit', 
function(event){event.preventDefault();my_func();});
var my_func = function() {
// HOW DO I PREVENT DEFAULT HERE???
// do something
}
```

Comment: When using EventListeners, use the event name and not the action. In the case of your answer, it should be addEventListener('click', ...) not addEventListener('onclick', ...)