# Django app button with two functionalities

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am building a Django app and on one of the HTML sheets I have a submit button that runs a function in views.py when clicked.

```
<input type="submit" id="senden" class="inputfiles"/>
<button for="senden" class="button" id="weiter_btn" >Submit</button>
```

But I want it to first run a javascript function on the client-side and then go on and run the function in views.py.
I tried to add onclick to the button element but that didn't work.

```
<input type="submit" id="senden" class="inputfiles"/>
<button for="senden" onclick="example()" class="button" id="weiter_btn" >Submit</button>
```

Should I maybe create another hidden button that runs the js function and then somehow connect it to the submit button?

---

UPDATE:

I've tried the first solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709140/how-to-prevent-default-on-form-submit) post.
Now it runs the javascript function but it doesn't go on to the function in the .py.
This is the js script:

```
<div>
        
        <script>
            var ocr = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                Tesseract.recognize(
                    document.getElementById('imgde').src,
                    'deu',
                    { logger: m => console.log(m) }
                ).then(({ data: {text}}) => {
                    console.log(text);
                    document.getElementById('txt_voc_de').innerHTML = ['<input type="hidden" name="txt_voc_de" id="txt_voc_de" value="',text, '"/>'].join('');
                })

                Tesseract.recognize(
                    document.getElementById('imgen').src,
                    'eng',
                    { logger: m => console.log(m) }
                ).then(({ data: {text}}) => {
                    console.log(text);
                    document.getElementById('txt_voc_en').innerHTML = ['<input type="hidden" name="txt_voc_en" id="txt_voc_en" value="',text, '"/>'].join('');
                })
                
                
   
                
            };

            var form = document.getElementById("imgForm");
            form.addEventListener("submit", ocr, false);
        </script>
        <input type="submit" id="senden" class="inputfiles" />
        <button for="senden" class="button" id="weiter_btn" >WEITER</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could run the `onsubmit` function with `preventDefault()` and then call the .py in the JavaScript function, after whatever it is that you want to do before it.

Something like this:

```
<script>
     function beforeSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        //your before submit logic       
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); 
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Click" onsubmit="beforeSubmit();" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I tried what you suggested but somehow it doesn't work. It just calls the .py.