# sending form data with javascript with XMLHttpRequest asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am sending some form data with an XMLHttpRequest

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", url, true);


xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
try {
    let data = JSON.stringify(sendForm);
    xhr.send(data);
    alert(xhr.status);
 }
 catch (error) {
     alert(error);
 }
```

This works as it will go into this after the alert pops up in the browser

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        location.href = 'thanks.html';
    }
```

and data will be inserted into the database as expected.  However, if I comment out the alert after the `xhr.send(data);` this code will no longer inserts data into the database or display the correct page, it just displays the js file.  If I set a break point at `xhr.send(data)` when I step past it is when the js file is displayed.
Any thoughts as to why the data is being sent if I include the `alert(xhr.status)` step in the code but not when I comment it out?  Also, any thoughts why the `try{}catch{}` is not catching the error?  Thanks I am not very familiar with javascript right now.

Comment: How are you triggering the XHR?

Comment: The code that's calling this is probably reloading the page. The alert delays that so you get the response from the AJAX and do the redirect.

Comment: Is it being called from a submit button? You probably forgot to prevent the default form submission.

Comment: Yes, Barmar the js and xhr is called with a submit button, where should I prevent the default form submission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent default on form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709140/how-to-prevent-default-on-form-submit)

Comment: @Christopher is there another way? if i do function SubmitForm() {preventDefault()...} that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You have to call the `event.preventDefault()` function of the event submitted during the onsubmit call. `onsubmit="function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }"`

Comment: Add your actual code and we can show more specifically how to fix it.

Comment: Got it figured out between @Barmar and Christopher thank you guys!!