# Prevent save button to submit form in Django admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

I wrote a control over some input in my admin form, which is executed on save buttons' click (I control a repetition of some inputs, but that's not important).

So, if this check fails, I alert a message, but I also need to avoid django admin to send this wrong request to the server. How can i do it in Javascript? (i'm using jQuery)

Comment: Remember that javascript is executed client-side. Any logic you put in to prevent a button being pressed can be subverted by a suitably determined user, so if the prevention of the request submission is vital to the security/integrity of your application then do not leave it up to javascript to prevent it.

Comment: @PeteTinkler I know that, but this isn't a very important control, it's only to avoid repetition of records with the same name, besides this is a solution for a webapp for a callcenter, I don't think anyone will try to subvert data :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("id_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

For old browsers look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript) (second answer).