# Execute javascript in Firefox extension popup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently taking my very first steps in extension development. At the moment I'm just trying to display some info in a popup that appears when I hit the button. The problem is that it is dynamic information, that I gather from a JSON-file on the internet. I could not get the data to show up in the pop-up however, and I've narrowed the problem down to the point that it just does not seem to run any Javascript at all...

I have a extremely simple code left:

manifest.json:

```
    {

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extention",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "",

  "icons": {
    "256": "icon/button.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "200": "icon/button.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Test Extention",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup/popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        html,body{width:300px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script>
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'testing';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the html-file directly in firefox, it displays "testing" as expected. When I run the extension however, I get a empty pop-up when clicking the new button.

I have also tried putting the js-code in a function, and calling that with a button, to see if it needed some time before js-code can be run, but that does not work either.

I am sure it is something extremely simple I'm missing, but I cannot find anything on this...

Comment: check the console of the addon debugger (about:debugging) or the browser console (ctrl+shift+j).

Comment: @the8472 Thanks for the tip, I did not know the console in about:debugging. When I open the pop-up it creates a error:
Content Security Policy: De instellingen van de pagina blokkeerden het laden van een bron op self (‘script-src moz-extension://b777829c-c282-42fd-829c-10b9c5e9332e’). Source: 
  document.getElementById('container').....

It is in Dutch, but translates roughly to:
Content Security Policy: the page settings blocked the loadingof a source on self

Comment: After searching on this error-message, I discovered that it is not possible to use js-code in the html-file itself. I have moved the code to its own js-file, and included it with <script src="..."></script>. This time, the text "testing" did appear.

I'm going to try the next step, and get the data to be fetchd from an online json.

Answer (score 9):

WebExtension APIs have a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy) applied to them by default. So it can't execute inline javascript code in popup HTML files.

Not only:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'testing';
</script>
```

But also:

```
<button onclick="alert('hello')">Hello</button>
```

If you touched this rule, you can get some error message in [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) and [Add-on Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging).

So, for fix this, use `<script src="..."></script>` rather than `<script>...</script>`.

Or, maybe set [Unsafe inline script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script) to [content_security_policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) key in manifest.json can fix this too. But MDN tells me:

> Note: Valid examples display the correct use of keys in CSP. However, extensions with 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline', remote script, blob, or remote sources in their CSP are not allowed for extensions listed on addons.mozilla.org due to major security issues.

in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy). It seems that not good way.

Comment: Combining your answer (using the `<script src="..."></script>` syntax) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410112/14349477) enabling me to listen to a `submit` event in JavaScript, I was able to execute code when clicking a submit button linked to a form, without touching the content security policy of the extension. Thanks!