# How do I wait for input to be filled in an html page and then print it's value to the console in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with an input field
Someone enters some text into it
They click a button

I want to grab the value of the input field AFTER they **click the button** with some JS code(client-side) and then print it to the console/save it to a file.

How would I go about doing this?
I've tried looking but I can't find anything like this at all :/

Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I listen to the form submit event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript)

Comment: You can't save it to a file client side if they're in a browser, but if you're using node import `fs`

Comment: @chbchb55 Incorrect. You can save text input to a file using javascript. Here is a simple example [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9yd62eum/)

Comment: @NewToJS, strictly programmatically speaking you can't, however, if you want the visitor to download the file that is possible

Comment: @chbchb55 Maybe this depends if *"save it to a file"* means a file on the server or allow the client to save it to file on their computer via download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should help you to achieve your goals.

```js
const inputNode = document.getElementById('input');
const buttonNode = document.getElementById('button');

buttonNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputValue = inputNode.value;
  
  // do what ever you wan't
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Er, this isn't working :P
I put `document.write("hi)` in place of the commented out code, but nothing comes :/

Comment: I placed the script src at the start of the body in the .html file lol @benvc
Thanks Roman!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
// This function is called by the HTML code onclick on the button
var get_content_of_input = function(){
    var user_input = document.getElementById("text_field").value;
    // Now you can use the variable user_input containing the text
}
```

```html
<input id="text_field">Please enter Text</input>
<button id="button" onclick="get_content_of_input()">Click here to sumbit</button>
```

The content of the text field will now be saved in the variable "user_input".