# Onsubmit with php value

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is possible while submiting form to send php value in onsubmit?
Like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return submitUserForm(<?php $this->id; ?>);">
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I listen to the form submit event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript)

Comment: You might want an `echo` in there if you want the PHP to actually do anything

Comment: Or `<?= $this->id ?>`. But yeah, it inserts the id into the inline JS, so why wouldn't it work? Provided it's a number, not text, that is.

Comment: <form onsubmit="return submitUserForm(<?php echo $this->id; ?>);"> is ok? thanks guys for help :)