# How would you make an iframe if the value is true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, login-script

I have a javascript login page (I know it's not secure!) How would I make the website create an iframe if the value is correct?

I have already tried window.location.assign but doesn't work! When you add any code it deletes the values in the inputs and puts the values you inserted in the url?

```
   <div class="box" id="loginbox">
   <h2>Login</h2>
   <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" onsubmit="return checkDetails();">
  <div class="inputBox">
  <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info" required />
    <label>Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
  <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info" required/>
    <label>Password</label>
    </div>
  <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login"/>

  </form>
  </div>
  <script>var remainingAttempts = 3;


   function checkDetails() {
    var name = form1.txtusername.value;
    var password = form1.txtpassword.value;
console.log('name', name);
console.log('password', password);
var validUsername = validateUsername(name);
var validPassword = validatePassword(password);
if (validUsername && validPassword) {
    alert('Login successful');
  document.getElementById("loginbox").remove();


  var next = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  next.src = 'https://codepen.io';
  next.classList.add("codepen");
  document.body.appendChild(next);
} else {
    form1.txtusername.value = '';
    form1.txtpassword.value = '';
    remainingAttempts--;

    var msg = '';
    if (validPassword) {
        msg += 'Username incorrect: ';
    } else if (validUsername) {
        msg += 'Password incorrect: ';
    } else {
        msg += 'Both username and password are incorrect: ';
    }

    msg += remainingAttempts + ' attempts left.';
    alert(msg);

    if (remainingAttempts <= 0) {
        alert('Closing window...');
        window.close();
    }
}

    return validUsername && validPassword;
  }

 function validateUsername(username) {
   return username == 'GG';
}

 function validatePassword(password) {
   return password == '123';
           }</script>
```

I want the page to create the iframe and remove the login box.

Comment: Why are you okay with it being insecure? Should we ever be doing something so blatantly insecure?

Comment: It's just a school project to see if you can make a login with javascript.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Your code to append the iframe to the document body is correct, and I have confirmed that it does work as expected.

Comment: When I use the code in a website it returns the url to https://example.org/?txtusername=GG&txtpassword=123&Login=Login     -------------------------------------------------------------------> Here is a live example     https://best-professor.glitch.me      The username is GG the pass is 123

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are triggering a form submission when your login button is clicked, which triggers a page load.

```
<input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login"/>
```

The submit input type type triggers this behaviour. To avoid this, bind to the submit event in the javascript rather than the HTML and use `preventDefault()` to prevent the page from reloading.

```
var ele = document.getElementById("loginbox");
if(ele.addEventListener){
    ele.addEventListener("submit", checkDetails, false);  //Modern browsers
} else if(ele.attachEvent){
    ele.attachEvent('onsubmit', checkDetails);            //Old IE
}

function checkDetails(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  // rest of your code
```

Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript/7410112#7410112), which you should read for more information about form submission events and how to handle them.