# how can i get a value from inside a function using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, token, hidden-field, login-script

here is the function from inside a script

```
function dosubmit()
  {
    if (getObj("Frm_Username").value == "")
    {
      getObj("errmsg").innerHTML = "Username cannot be empty.";
      getObj("myLayer").style.visibility = "visible" ;
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      getObj("LoginId").disabled = true;
      getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";
      document.fLogin.submit();
    }
  }
```

i want to get the value of `getObj("Frm_Logintoken")`
as i can't pull the value  from  `#Frm_Logintoken`

using `document.getElementById("#Frm_Logintoken")`
this gives me null

because Frm_Logintoken only gets it's value when i click submit .

```
<input type="hidden" name="Frm_Logintoken" id="Frm_Logintoken" value="">
```

full [page code](https://hastebin.com/tuhazuhipe.xml)

i found this online `/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/g` 
but when i run it ... it gives me the same line again !
it's full code
https://hastebin.com/gurosatuna.xml

Comment: Isn't it always `3`?

Comment: @Phil  no it gets increased by one every successful login

Comment: What do you want to do with the value and more importantly, **when**?

Comment: try `document.getElementById("Frm_Logintoken")` without the number sign

Comment: _"number sign"_, also known as _"pound sign"_ or _"hash"_ (or _"sharp"_ if you're into musical notation)

Comment: it gave me this `<input type="hidden" name="Frm_Logintoken" id="Frm_Logintoken" value="">`
........
the value is used to login into the page . using php to curl 
[link](https://pastebin.com/9gAaR516) .. i still want to convert this code to javascript ... when to use it ? after i get the value of the token.

Comment: @Phil..........

Comment: @mina .........?

Comment: huh... sorry :(

Comment: @Phil i have searched google with the id frashnum ... and found this code in a forum ... would it help ?

[link](https://pastebin.com/n6H4SKXP)
i have posted the link  inside a pastbin cause it said something about pages that breaks fast and refused to post it .

Comment: what does this even mean ?
`/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/g`
when i run it ... it gives me the line again !

Comment: have you tried with.val() or .text() or .InnerHTML() to see what value these give you.

Comment: aren't them all are the same ...    .InnerHTML()  gives me ""
and the others i don't know there full command but i think they will return the same value .

Comment: hi would this help ? https://gist.github.com/ali-essam/80b58ea170051a96108b5f320754564f

Answer (score 0):

First:

Your checking if a value is empty with JS. However this is NOT needed as HTML does this for you. Add a attribute required and the form will not submit as long this value is empty

> Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Second:

You could use the event handler 'on submit'. The code is not complete enough to know if u did this but I suppose you just added a Click handler on the button.

> Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

When combining these two, you always have a username filled in and the code only executes when submitted. I hope this helps, if not please leave a comment and I will edit this answer.

EDIT: the answer on this SO will also help (not the checked on but the one below)

[How can I listen to the form submit event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript)

Comment: "Add a attribute required and the form will not submit as long this value is empty"
it's already there !!
but     document.fLogin.submit(); refreshes the page and there is a lock after 3 wrong tries ... and it's not just like clicking the button as it just shows the pop up 
of   Username cannot be empty.
....
about the second part i don't own the code it's an already written code so i don't know if editing the code after the page loads helps ...

Comment: hi would this help ? https://gist.github.com/ali-essam/80b58ea170051a96108b5f320754564f