# How to use enter to append my <li> element to my list?

Tags: javascript, button, enter, onkeypress

So right now I have a working to-do list where in order to add a list item, you have to click a button. I wish to also allow the user to hit "enter" in order to do the same thing as the button.

Below is the js code I used to create a new li element and append it to my list.

```
function newElement(){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputValue));
        if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
      }

    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
```

This is my HTML code for the button that runs the newElement() function above.

```
<input type ="text" id="myInput"  placeholder="Type Task Here" >
        <button class="submitButton" type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add To List</button>
```

Comment: The best way would probably be to handle the form `submit` event, and call `newElement()` there. Then you can also remove the `onclick` from the button. You likely want to [use `event.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript) too, but you haven't provided your whole form/HTML (or did you?), so it's not clear how your form is currently set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event and check the `keyCode`

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    newElement();
  }
});
```

Or if you just want this behavior on the `input`, try to add the event listener on the `input` only

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("Enter key detected.")
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type and Enter" />
```

Comment: it should work, added a snippet in place for the second one. maybe check elsewhere in your REAL code

Comment: Thank you! I played around with your code and changed document.querySelector to document.getElementById and it worked! Thank you!!!!